# alguien sabe como realizar excel con asp c# con store procedure con parametros

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy realizando un reporte con un procedimiento almacenado que tiene como entradas 3 entras uno es el monto, fecha,opcion.y en mi pagina tiene 3 input  entradas para que ingrese y cuando presione exportar se baje un archivo excel el problema es que me muestra un error **"Error al convertir el valor del parámetro de DropDownList a String".** Quisiera que me ayuden Porfavor

```
  protected void ExportExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
           string query = "COMISION_DIC16";
            //string query = "SELECT TOP 10 codigomoneda, idcredito, numerocredito FROM credito..credito;";
           // query += "SELECT TOP 10  idorigencredito, segmentotasa, segmentocartera FROM credito..credito;";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {


                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("TP", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = txtTC.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("Fecha_FDM", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = txtFecha_FDM.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("OPC", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = OPC;

                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(ds);

                            //Set Name of DataTables.
                            ds.Tables[0].TableName = "idcredito";
                            ds.Tables[1].TableName = "numerocredito";


                            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
                            {
                                foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                                {
                                    //Add DataTable as Worksheet.
                                    wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
                                }

                                //Export the Excel file.
                                Response.Clear();
                                Response.Buffer = true;
                                Response.Charset = "";
                                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Cuadro_1_dic16.xlsx");
                                using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                                {
                                    wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                                    MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                                    Response.Flush();
                                    Response.End();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Exactamente en cuál línea del código te da ese error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucion :

```
  protected void ExportExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string query = "Rpt_Refinanciado"; //"COMISION"

        using (  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion()))
        {


            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 90000000;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("f_ini", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtFecha_Ini.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("f_fin", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txt_Fecha_Fin.Text;
             // cmd.Parameters.Add("OPC", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = OPC.SelectedItem.Value;



                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;


                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(ds);

                        //Set Name of DataTables.
                        ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Rpt-Comision";



                        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
                        {
                            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                            {
                                //Add DataTable as Worksheet.
                                wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
                            }

                            //Export the Excel file.
                            Response.Clear();
                            Response.Buffer = true;
                            Response.Charset = "";
                            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Reporte_Comision.xlsx");

                            using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                                Response.Flush();
                                Response.End();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Según entiendo el problema es al mandar el valor seleccionado

intenta cambiar esta linea

si necesitas el valor del dropdownlist

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("OPC", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = OPC.SelectedItem.Value;
```

si necesitas el texto del elemento del dropdownlist

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("OPC", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = OPC.SelectedItem.Text;
```

podrías se mas especifico con tu error ya que el problema que comentas es muy diferente al titulo de la pregunta.

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Barraganubc si esque lo que deceo es exportar un excel con procedimiento de la base de datos pero cuando hago con procedure no me logra importar y asi maso menos es el codigo que hago pero no me logra esque tambien en el error no especifica mucho lo que es el error

Answer (score 1):

Este método, se utiliza para agregar el parámetro de un store procedure, revísalo por fa si tienes alguna duda me dices. Tal vez te pueda servir para pasar los parámetros directamente, ya que especificas desde el inicio que tipo de dato es y el nombre del campo.

```
public void AgregarParametro(string NombreParametro, System.Data.SqlDbType TipoParametro, Object Valor)
{
    try
    {
        this.cmd.Parameters.Add(NombreParametro, TipoParametro).Value = Valor;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("No se pudo agregar el parámetro. " + ex.Message.ToString().Trim());
    }
}
```